# What's exactly meant by the "slippery when wet" report on ATIS?

Tags: performance-calculation

I read [this discussion](http://www.pprune.org/archive/index.php/t-15288.html) and discovered the definition of "slippery when wet" from [this advisory circular](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_25-32_Final.pdf) but I'm still having a hard time understanding why the runway condition is expressed as "slippery when wet" rather than just as "slippery." My guess is that the wet runway normally doesn't bring a slippery runway condition but it sometimes does and in that case it's expressed as "slippery when wet" rather than just "slippery." Is my guess correct?

Comment: @Federico Corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the runway condition is expressed as "slippery when wet" rather than just as "slippery."

Because the runway is normally not slippery, and thus it cannot be described simply as "slippery", but it must be specified **when** this occurs, particularly when it is wet it is slippery.

Saying only "slippery" would mean that the runway is always slippery, and is not the case.

Saying only "wet" does not convey the information that it is also slippery in that condition. (and you want to specify this because not all runways are slippery when wet)

It is not said "slippery when icy" because "when icy" everything is slippery, so that does not need specification, "icy" is sufficient.

"slippery when snowy" I never heard of it, generally because either the runway gets snowploughed fast enough, or because when there is too much snow the runway gets closed.

Comment: I feel this answer is along the lines of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m5qxZm_JqM

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if the runway is slippery due to ice, is it reported as "slippery when icy" and if the runway is slippery due to snow, is it reported as "slippery with snow"?

Comment: @lemonincider no, edited